# Does privacy policy need to be in all languages an app supports when uploading to app store?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

It is mandatory for all apps submitted on the App Store to provide privacy policy.

- https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#privacy

As I understand, a privacy policy link must be provided in all the languages an app is localized in.

However, can I provide privacy policy in English for all translations, or do I need to have it translated?

It is a big effort, as there aren't very many resources available in local languages for the "legalise".

Comment: This is something that only Apple can answer.

Comment: Do you have any info about that? Should I have it in all languages that supported by app?

Comment: @eis ah, thank you for your replay. I was just confused because of its negative rate. Now I'll upvote it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not mandatory to provide privacy policy translations for all the languages your app supports.

Additionally, as I can infer from your post, since your app's primary language is English, privacy policy text in English should suffice.

If you still have concerns or have specific questions, as a paid developer program member, you can seek help from [Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/) and get answers for specific queries.